# How to use existing sqlservert database for hibernate classes

Tags: java, hibernate

I currently have an application that works and update a sqlserver DB with over 50 entity, I would use the same DB to create a parallel java program with hibernate and get a inside persistent class system.

1. I do not care to deal with all the entities and attributes in DB
2. I want create persistent classes for me interesting,using attributes in different entities.
3. I do not want to change the db,  I do not want to create problems to the old application
4. The new program is for statistics intentions,the refresh from the DB can be sporadic

what in your opinion are the best ways to act in a comfortable and agile way?
I can move with basic in DBMS and Hibernate.

This is for me something new,so if it is possible, please provide me a list of clear step and examples or tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.
First you have to use a JDBC driver for SQLServer like this one : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt484311(v=sql.110).aspx

After, just follow a tutorial for using hibernate : 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/quickstart/html_single/